# UML indicating the inheritance of many separate use case diagrams

Tags: uml

I understand the appropriate use of extend and include , however all the examples I could find draw single large use case diagram with extend or include within the system boundary of that single use case diagram.

Our current project has a base use case diagram with different specialisations from that base use case diagram. Each diagram is on a different page in the document and due to their combined size, including all of them into a single diagram is not a good idea. I would like to know if there is a standard or conventional way of communicating this inheritance tree of separate use case diagrams? If there is not, what would you recommend is the best way to go forward with this dilemma?

Comment: UML is not about diagramming! Also I don't understand what you mean with specialization in the context of use cases. This is a very rare and to avoid use. Can you provide some of your work?

Answer (score 0):

[Uses Cases inheritance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CpKK.jpg)

Does this image extracted from UML speficitaion helps you ?
A point which is not clear for me, are you dealing with Use case inheritance or diagram inheritance ? To tell the truth, I never used diagram inheritance and I am not sure if this is possible and the meaning of a such usage of inheritance.